# How to declare an instance which its type is user-defined in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Simply my question is about defining the type of an instance in run time, and this type is user-defined.
Something which looks like this:

```
Type instance1;
```

In run time, the user is going to choose for example "int", then there 'll be,

```
int instance1;
```

Any suggestions?? is downCasting efficient here?

Comment: Wow, it smells horribly wrong somehow. Are You writing an application, the user of which has to know it's code and tell it what types to use? What are You trying to do if I may ask?

Comment: A little more info about what you are willing to archieve would be very usefull. Where does the user defined type come from? Does the enduser chose it from, lets say, a dropdown box in the GUI?

Comment: @Maciej: exactly. That is why I proposed generics. Since c# is a statically typed language, you should also write code that way. The `dynamic` keyword may be not the right approach to solve problems in a strictly typed language (People wrote great programs before c#4 and `dynamic` :) ). Perhaps Shaza has to use the reflector, if the type is really _end_user defined, but he didnt say anything concrete.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear enough, I'm working on an application that developer can use it for building a recursive methods, and I need the answer for the previous question because I'm building the method through some inputs that developer gives me, so one of these inputs should be the method's output, which can be chosen through a dropdown box.

Comment: Sorry, I still cant figure out how you imagined to do that. How is that method built? Maybe you are better off using an interpreter of some dynamic script language (python/ruby/vbscript/javascript) to let the user write his recursive method with his own code? Just a suggestion...

Comment: I am asking you all this stuff, because there is not way to do exactly what you described in your question in c#. But there are several ways to express the same (reflector/generics/`dynamic` keyword/`object` that is casted to some type). I am just not sure which one of these methods fits your application best, and ends up in a clean and expressive code. That should be the goal, right?

Comment: Right, I'm still working on it, I'll reply as soon as I figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for are generics. Read an introduction [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28VS.80%29.aspx).

For example you would declare the class, you want that user defined type to be in, like that:

```
class MyClass<T>
{
    private T instance1 = default(T);

    public MyClass(T initalvalue)
    {
        instance1 = initalvalue;
    }

    //... some more code
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid, that generics is not what the OP is looking for. Shaza is talking about the end user using running application, not a programmer who uses his code. The type is supposed to be chosen at runtime

Comment: @Maciej: that is just speculation, as long as Shaza isnt saying what he really wants to do.

Comment: I commented on the basic post what I'm working on and BTW, I'm a "she" :)

Comment: @Shaza: Sorry for that. Didnt hear your name before.

Answer (score 1):

Without you explaining more details of what you are looking to accomplish, you can either use a [generic](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/031024.htm) method<sup>*</sup>, you can use [C# 4's `dynamic` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx), or you can use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28VS.80%29.aspx) to create instances of the given type.

<sup>*</sup>The generic method will work well if the type can be known at compile-time or if it's one of only a finite set of types, and you'll pick a type that was named at compile-time (i.e. user will say one of `int`, `char`, or `double`, and you'll use the correct generic accordingly).  If it's completely indeterminable, you'll still need to use reflection to instantiate the generic with the type given at run time.

Comment: +1. Yes, I thought about solving it with generics if, like you said, there is a defined set of types known at compile time. I'm no fan of using `dynamic` if you dont interop with a dynamic language. I think its quite ugly to turn c# into something it isnt: a dynamic language.

Answer (score 0):

dynamic Keyword in C# 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I presume, this is what you are looking for:

```
Type myType = typeof(int);
int value = Activatior.CreateInstance(myType);
```

In .NET 4, the dynamic keyword is perhaps more effective and convenient.